# Could not access user defaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am getting this on console on accessing the user defaults:

```
(lldb) po UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_username")
```

> -[__NSCFData _getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x611000027280
>   error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 56.1 58.1.
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation

Comment: remove app and run again project.

Comment: @AnandSuthar Actually I this accessed via console

Comment: did you remove app from simulator or device ?

Comment: @KKRocks for first installation  it is working fine. when I run it again, It goes to exception

Comment: yes it is the problem ....at where you set object for this user_username ?

Comment: at there you set data instead of string .

Comment: Edit your question with the code that put data into UserDefaults for the "user_username" key.